# How do i extract a number from a url using PHP

Tags: php

I have an SMF website and i'm actually trying to get some header information which includes the title of a particular thread, the url but i've been finding it difficult to get the unique link affixed to the url using PHP.

Here's the url: `http://example.com/index.php?topic=6449.msg6858`

I'm actually looking for a way to extract the number **6449**, I've tried to use the php GET function but it doesn't work.

Comment: which `GET` function?

Answer (score 2):

```
$parts = explode('.', $_GET['topic']);
echo $parts[0];

// PHP 5.4+
echo explode('.', $_GET['topic'])[0];
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/W1OFRF)

This would work, too

```
echo (int) $_GET['topic'];
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6qG9Wj)

Comment: I forgot to add that the link will be dynamic and not predetermined.

Comment: +1 for your second answer

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a combination of [substr](https://www.php.net/substr) and [strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos) (to find the first occurence of a period)

```
$number = substr($_GET['topic'], 0, strpos($_GET['topic'], '.'));
// 6449
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
if (preg_match("/([\\d]+)([.]{1}msg[\\d]+)/", $_GET["topic"], $arr) == 1) {
    echo $arr[1];
} else { 
    trigger_error("not found", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```